# Place Dict list values in the text file template

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
{'test_name': ['D S', 'C S'],
 'date': ['23/04/2021', '02/05/2021'],
 'link1': ['smk.com', 'xyz.com '],
 'link2': ['pst.com', 'abc.com ']}
```

From the dict, need to insert the values in the template file.

(Template file) file.txt

```
Pending of taking test {test_name} was due on {date}. Follow the below link
X_link : {link1} --> replace with xyz from one.txt

y_link : {link2} --> replace with abc from one.txt
```

Expected output:

**In Iteration 1:**

```
Pending of taking test D S was due on 23/04/2021. Follow the below link
X_link : smk.com

y_link : pst.com
```

**In Iteration 2:**

```
Pending of taking test c S was due on 02/05/2021. Follow the below link
X_link : xyz.com

y_link : abc.com
```

Tried to implement but unable to print as expected

```
        requirements = {}
        for req in reqs:
            list_values = [x for x in reqs[req]]
            print(list_values)
            for val in list_values:
                print(val)
                requirements.update( {reqs : val} )
        with open(r'file.txt') as file2:
                m = ''
                for line in file2:
                    m+=line.format(**requirements)
                    print(m)
```

Comment: What is the code that you have attempted? We will not do your homework for you.... we will help you with the problems you face whilst coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to transform your replacements dict to only include the value relevant in each operation. You can do this by creating a generator for each index `i`, that will create a new dictionary `{key: val[i]}` for each item in the original replacements dict. Like this:

```
replacements = { <your dict> }

iterations = 2  # However many values you have in each list
for current_replacements in ({key: val[i] for key, val in replacements.items()}
                             for i in range(iterations)):
  formatted = template_string.format(**current_replacements)
  # do something with formatted output
```

In the for loop iterations `current_replacements` will have values:

- `{'test_name': 'D S', 'date': '23/04/2021', 'link1': 'smk.com', 'link2': 'pst.com'}`
- `{'test_name': 'C S', 'date': '02/05/2021', 'link1': 'xyz.com ', 'link2': 'abc.com '}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

    data  = {'test_name': ['D S', 'C S'],
     'date': ['23/04/2021', '02/05/2021'],
     'link1': ['smk.com', 'xyz.com '],
     'link2': ['pst.com', 'abc.com ']}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
    
    with open('file.txt', 'w+') as f:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            f.write(f'Pending of taking test {row["test_name"]} was due on {row["date"]}. Follow the below link\n')
            f.write(f'X_link : {row["link1"]}\n')
            f.write(f'Y_link : {row["link2"]}\n')
    
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
Pending of taking test D S was due on 23/04/2021. Follow the below link
X_link : smk.com
Y_link : pst.com
Pending of taking test C S was due on 02/05/2021. Follow the below link
X_link : xyz.com 
Y_link : abc.com
```